# How to re-render child on parent event in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple table with rendered rows. Each row holds a component:

```
return this.data.list.map((item, index) => {

        return (
            <tr key={"item-" + item._id} onMouseEnter={this._toggleActions.bind(this, index)} onMouseLeave={this._toggleActions.bind(this, index)}>
                <td>{item.title}</td>
                <td>
                    {item.desc}
                    <ItemActions key={"item-child-" + item._id} active={[whatToPassHere?]} />
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
```

The `ItemActions` component holds a list of buttons. On mouseover table row i want to activate this component with a prop but i have no idea how to do it. Should i set a state in `_toggleActions`? Is my structure completely wrong? thanks for advice

Comment: I'd set a state as you said. Looks fine to me.

Comment: any time parent state changes the children are re-rendered